# vs-code MS Python extension can't find autopep8 on Linux

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Debian Stretch (9)

Extension: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python

About VS Code:

```
Version: 1.32.3
Commit: a3db5be9b5c6ba46bb7555ec5d60178ecc2eaae4
Date: 2019-03-14T23:38:49.842Z
Electron: 3.1.6
Chrome: 66.0.3359.181
Node.js: 10.2.0
V8: 6.6.346.32
OS: Linux x64 4.9.0-8-amd64

hbarta@olive:~$ which autopep8
/usr/bin/autopep8
hbarta@olive:~$
```

The extension reports that it can't find autopep8 which I have installed via the Debian package manager. I can't figure out how to tell the extension where to find it.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried reloading/restarting VS code yet? If I remember correctly that's also something you need to do for package installations to apply.

Comment: Tried that - did not work. And FWIW, Extensions may not require a reload/restart any more, but it is always worth a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To tell Code where autopep8 is, open the command palette(ctrl+alt+p), find "Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)" and add the following lines between the brackets (`{}`)

```
    "python.formatting.provider": "autopep8",
    "python.formatting.autopep8Path": "/usr/bin/autopep8",
```

Then close and re-start Code.

Comment: Yes, Thanks!
Errata: On Debian/Stretch the key stroke to get into preferences is <ctrl><,>. Go figure. (Desktop uses a lot of <ctrl><alt> keystrokes.) And the trick to getting to the JSON settings was to click on the curly braces in the upper left of the settings page. Also interesting that this was not needed on Debian/Buster. On both the path is `/usr/bin/autopep8`.